# JavaScript ES6 promises

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

Question: What is the difference between these four promises?

```
doSomething().then(function () { return doSomethingElse(); });

doSomething().then(function () { doSomethingElse(); });

doSomething().then(doSomethingElse());

doSomething().then(doSomethingElse);
```

Comment: Depends what `doSomethingElse()` returns. What do you think the differences are?

Comment: You should also consider `doSomething().then(function(value) { return doSomethingElse(value); })` (hint, hint: that's equivalent to the last case)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**Option 1:**

```
doSomething().then(function () { return doSomethingElse(); });
```

This executes `doSomething()`, then when it resolves, it executes `doSomethingElse()` and the resolved value of the promise chain is the resolved value or return value of `doSomethingElse()`.  No arguments are passed to `doSomethingElse()`.

If you were to summarize this option, you'd say it was:

**Chained in Sequence, with no parameter passing.**

---

**Option 2:**

```
doSomething().then(function () { doSomethingElse(); });
```

Same as option 1, except the resolved value of the promise chain is `undefined` because there is no return value from the `.then()` handler.  Any return value from `doSomethingElse()`, whether a promise or a value is ignored.

If you were to summarize this option, you'd say it was:

**Executed in Sequence (not chained), with no parameter passing.**

---

**Option 3:**

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse());
```

This is pretty much never what you want.  This executes `doSomething()` and then, before `doSomething()` has resolved, it also executes `doSomethingElse()` and passes the return value from `doSomethingElse()` as the `.then()` handler.  This is a coding mistake unless `doSomethingElse()` returns a function to be used as the `.then()` handler.

If you were to summarize this option, you'd say it was:

**Executed Immediately, Probably a Bug**

---

**Option 4:**

```
doSomething().then(doSomethingElse);
```

This is the same as option 1 except that the resolved value from `doSomething()` is passed as the first argument to `doSomethingElse(val)`.  This is structurally the same as this:

```
doSomething().then(function(result) { return doSomethingElse(result)});
```

If you were to summarize this option, you'd say it was:

**Chained in Sequence, with parameter passing.**

---

Other Notes:

1. If `doSomethingElse()` returns a promise, then only Options 1 and 4 will add that promise to the chain (because they are the only options that return the promise from the `.then()` handler) so the chain will wait for that promise to resolve.
2. In options 1, 2 and 4, if `doSomethingElse()` throws a synchronous exception, then the promise chain will become rejected with the exception as the reason.  In option 3, the function is executed outside the promise chain so if it throws a synchronous exception, it will throw to a higher scope (similar to if `doSomething()` threw synchronously).

Answer (score 0):

In first case, after resolving promise returned by `doSomething()`, callback is invoked. Callback function can return another promise (that's why we call promises 'chainable'). In your case, `doSomethingElse()` is expected to return another promise.

In second case, nothing is returned by callback function, thus next promises in execution chain will be invoked, but with undefined parameter.

In third case, callback function is provided as result of `doSomethingElse()` function.

And finally, `doSomethingElse` is expected to be a function, which will be executed after fulfilling first promise.

Comment: The next promises would be triggered, they would just receive undefined there (in the second case), see for example [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/or5xkj34/1/)